# problems with lion 10.8.3 on the last iMac 27"

Tags: mac

I have tried to typeset very basic documents and it does not work! It cannot find documents like `book.class` or `bk12.clo`. I have checked all settings and seem OK (at least the work very well on my airbook an d on any other mac I have ever used). Is there somebody knowing what to do?

Comment: 10.8.3 is Mountain Lion. Have you installed a tex distribution?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Comment: Statements like "it does not work!" don't provide much diagnostic information. Could you tell us a bit more about your computer setup? E.g., did installation of MacTeX2012 proceed without errors? Which editor do you use: TeXshop, TeXworks, or something else?

Comment: If you are trying to find them in Finder, you have to make sure you 'include system files'. And I suppose you mean `book.cls` instead of `book.class`.